# ssh localhost working, but not from ip address, even with firewall allow

Tags: linux, ssh, login, ubuntu-18.04

I'm currently running into the issue that I cannot ssh into my machine remotely. I've first tried to ssh localhost from my Ubuntu 18.04 machine with OpenSSH configured, which works. However, when trying to access via the IP address of the machine natively, It times out. I've virtually tried all the suggestions I've seen.

I can walk through the steps I've taken:

1. logging in with verbose output

   ```
   OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
   debug2: resolving "73.162.76.69" port 22
   debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to 73.162.76.69 [73.162.76.69] port 22.
   ```

   ...

eventually it times out around 2 minutes (120) -- which is specified by the config.

2. checking if sshd is active:

   ```
   ps -A | grep sshd
   9069 ?        00:00:00 sshd
   9074 ?        00:00:00 sshd
   9114 ?        00:00:00 sshd
   9115 ?        00:00:00 sshd
   ```
3. Checking if firewall policy is allowing connection:

   ```
   sudo ufw status
   Status: active

   To                         Action      From
   --                         ------      ----
   22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
   OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
   22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
   OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
   ```

I've also tried iptables, but don't quite know how to interpret it. 
I've power cycled, purged and reinstalled the ssh server.

I've also restarted the router to ensure that it wasn't the issue -- to no avail.

Are there any other things I can try to deal with this issue?

My last option would be to re-install Ubuntu ... I don't have too much on this machine, but it does take time restoring everything I will need.

Comment: What audit logs says? hope you didn't added entry to hosts.deny.

Comment: Might need to try installing and running tcpdump on the server.  `tcpdump -qni any port 22 and host clientip`  Replacing the clientip with the  actual IP of your client, maybe 73.162.76.69?  Might also want to verify that ssh is listening `ss -ntlp | grep sshd`

Comment: @asktyagi -- how do i access the audit logs?

Comment: @Zoredache -- I tried ss -nltp | grep sshd -- it returned nothing.

Comment: check under `/var/log` dir.

Answer (score 0):

If timeout occur, it should be a bad firewall rule.

Allow it via iptables to quick test it :

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

If it not work try to allow output too :

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I tried these. It's still hanging with the same ouput